# How to set minimum-/maximum-size of FileDialog? - SWT - Java

Tags: java, swt, minimum-size

I hava a `DirectoryDialog` like this:

```
private static void openFiles() {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    DirectoryDialog directoryDialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN | SWT.MULTI);
    directoryDialog.setFilterPath("c:\\");
    Files[] files = new File(directoryDialog.open().listFiles());
    shell.close();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

And how`can I now for example set the minimum size?

I've tryed out `shell.setMinimumSize(500, 500)`, but it didn't work!

Comment: DirectoryDialog and FileDialog are just thin wrappers around the OS specific dialogs. They look very difererent on the various platforms - and have different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set the size of a `DirectoryDialog`. The size and position are determined by the OS.

Related: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/142845/

---

If you absolutely need to enforce a minimum size, you will need to implement your own. For custom dialogs I would recommend taking a look at a JFace [`Dialog`](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/Dialog.html) and its subclasses.

Here is a good article about SWT and JFace dialogs: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDialogs/article.html#jface-dialogs.

---

I also found a custom directory dialog which is just implemented using a `Shell`, so you would naturally have full control over size and position: http://esus.com/creating-an-swt-directorydialog/